# Conectar um botão com uma tela lcd pyqt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt-4

Boa tarde pessoal!

Preciso desenvolver uma calculadora em pyqt 4, mas não sei como ligar os botões de número/operações ao visor lcd virtual. Já pesquisei, mas não achei nada que resolvesse meu problema. Alguém pode me ajudar? O que fiz até agora está aqui  (me perdoem pelo codigo enrolado, sou inciante!!

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

def __init__(self):
    super(Example, self).__init__()

    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):

   grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
   self.setLayout(grid)

   lcd = QtGui.QLCDNumber(self)
   grid.addWidget(lcd, 0,1)

   um = QtGui.QPushButton('1', self)
   grid.addWidget(um, 1,1)
   dois = QtGui.QPushButton('2', self)
   grid.addWidget(dois, 1,2)
   tres = QtGui.QPushButton('3', self)
   grid.addWidget(tres, 1,3)
   quatro = QtGui.QPushButton('4', self)
   grid.addWidget(quatro, 2,1)
   cinco = QtGui.QPushButton('5', self)
   grid.addWidget(cinco, 2,2)
   seis = QtGui.QPushButton('6', self)
   grid.addWidget(seis, 2,3)
   sete = QtGui.QPushButton('7', self)
   grid.addWidget(sete, 3,1)
   oito = QtGui.QPushButton('8', self)
   grid.addWidget(oito, 3,2)
   nove = QtGui.QPushButton('9', self)
   grid.addWidget(nove, 3,3)
   zero= QtGui.QPushButton('0', self)
   grid.addWidget(zero, 4,1)
   mais= QtGui.QPushButton('+', self)
   grid.addWidget(mais, 4,2)
   menos= QtGui.QPushButton('-', self)
   grid.addWidget(menos, 4,3)
   vezes= QtGui.QPushButton('*', self)
   grid.addWidget(vezes, 5,1)
   dividir= QtGui.QPushButton('/', self)
   grid.addWidget(dividir, 5,2)
   igual= QtGui.QPushButton('=', self)
   grid.addWidget(igual, 5,3)

   self.move(300, 150)
   self.setWindowTitle('Calculadora')
   self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Tem algum código do que já fez?

Comment: Sim, completei a questão com o que fiz até agora :)

Comment: Por "ligar os botões de números ao lcd virtual", você diz vincular os eventos  dos botões a exibição de valores no lcd?

Comment: Sim, exatamente

Comment: Você pode usar o evento [clicked](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python_Tutorial_ClickableButton) do seu `QPushButton` e cada vez que clicar mostrar algo no seu lcd usando o método `display()`. Defina uma função que exibe algo no lcd, e chame ela quando o botão for clicado, com: `sete.clicked.connect(exibe_no_lcd(lcd,valor))`

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer isso capturando o evento do `QPushButton` no momento em que é clicado. O evento em questão é o `clicked`.

**Ex**: Supondo que queremos exibir uma mensagem no `lcd` quando o botão `um` for clicado.

1. Vou definir uma função( bem simples, apenas para um melhor entendimento), para receber a `msg` que será mostrada em tela em tempo de execução:

   `def exibe_no_lcd(msg):
        #chama o metodo display() para exibir no lcd
        lcd.display(msg)`

E uma função apenas para chamar a função que exibe no `exibe_no_lcd()`:

```
def botao_um_clicado():
     exibe_no_lcd("Eu sou o numero 1!")
```

2. Agora vinculamos a função que será chamada quando o botão for clicado:

   `um.clicked.connect(botao_um_clicado)`

#### Referências:

- Na [wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python_Tutorial_ClickableButton) tem um tutorial simples sobre o uso do evento `clicked`;
- No [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26817039/displaying-numbers-on-qlcdnumber-widget) tem uma pergunta sobre o uso do `display()`;
- Ainda no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080731/call-a-function-when-a-button-is-pressed-pyqt) tem uma pergunta sobre a chamada de uma função ao clicar em um `QPushButton`.